# How to get Paypal cart to load into a lightbox

Tags: html, ajax, paypal

I just putting finishing touches to my website and everytime the links to add to cart are clicked it takes the users to the paypal cart . Is there anyway to load this paypal cart page into a lightbox. Or inside a frame?  Becuase all my internal links are loaded with ajax into an appointed Div. So the paypal cart returns the users to the homepage instead of the section where they are making the purchase from. i would like to give my users the full customer experience and keep them engaged on my website

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Minicart](http://minicartjs.com/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=”utf-8″ />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1″ />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@minicartjs.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Product" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1″ />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00″ />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input class="discount_val" type="hidden" name="discount_amount_cart" value="">
<strong>Test Product</strong>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" />
</fieldset>
</form>



<script src="minicart.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
paypal.minicart.render();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added a complete example [here](http://www.techycommerce.com/mincart-add-to-cart-avoid-page-redirection/)

Comment: Let me make sure I am understanding I put that 1st half of the code before the closing body or html tag? And my return page is my home page but there are no products listed for sale nor is there buy or add to cart buttons? Can i put this script into a php and ajax load it into a lightbox?

Comment: This didnt work for me do i have to use the paypal button form? Or can i use the html from the email option? Also do i place this on my index page or the page where the products are listed... Sorry im still learning....

Comment: I just gave you a working HTML page, just will need to just copy it,save it as html and run it, you will see it working.

Comment: The page you provided me with is only showing text input fields that are suppose to be hidden

Comment: can you copy the above code in the updated answere and save it as .html and run in your browser?

Comment: Yes that is what i have done visit my website hover over he menu and select shop so you can see what i see www.foreverthaempire.com with my index page being php should i switch it to html?

Answer (score 0):

Minicart will show only the cart page that has the PayPal checkout button. But once you click on that button, you will get redirected to PayPal to complete the payment flow. Are you looking for a solution where the user stays on your site and the entire cart + payment experience runs off of a lightbox? If so, look at "Digital Goods for Express Checkout" (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/). But keep in mind this should be only used for digital goods (such as downloads, etc.). Hope this helps.

Comment: I want the user to be able to add multiple things to the cart without it forwarding to paypal everytime they click add to cart button and minicart isnt working for me on html or php.... And if i can get them to process payment from my site as well that would be great

Comment: I want the minicart to function like it does on the demo page for the product that is ideal do i need something else on my paypal account? Do i need digital goods activated to get this lightbox for checkout option?

Comment: no need to sign-up for digital goods to use minicart, you just need basic html,php skill to incorporate this).

Comment: Does it make a difference that i am usuing the latest version of jQuery? sorry just trying to get this working its literally the last thing to get my site totally functioning and ready for launching